# Remove null characters from WideString in Delphi 2006

Tags: delphi, unicode

I have a WideString variable containing some data but when the string was assigned some extra nulls where added at more or less random places in the data. I now need to strip these nulls out of the variable. If it had been a string I would have checked each Char to see if Char(x) = 0 but as this is a WideString I dont think this work? How can I best strip these out?

I'm using Delphi 2006

Comment: A note on terminology: *NULL* (all caps, two L's) is the C and C++ macro designating the pointer that doesn't point anywhere, a.k.a. the *null pointer*. *NUL* is the symbol for the ASCII character at index zero, a.k.a. the *null character*. Please only write *NULL* in all caps if you're talking about the pointer; otherwise, just capitalize it like an ordinary English word: "some extra null characters were added," "a null-terminated string," "the contract is null and void."

Comment: Thanks Rob. Question updated accordingly

Comment: With a widestring you can just use widechar in exactly the same way as you would with the ansi versions. That also addresses the other concerns about the difference between a zero leading byte and a zero widechar that others have raised. They're right in that stipping all the zero bytes out of a widestring would be entertaining but not useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're seeing probably aren't null characters. They're probably just the upper eight bits of a character with a code-point value less than 256.

If you really do have null characters in your string that aren't supposed to be there, the first thing you should do is figure out how they're getting there. There's probably a bug in your program if they're there when they shouldn't be.

If the code that generates the string is bug-free and you still have unwanted null characters, then you can remove them fairly easily. The common way to remove stuff from a string is with the [`Delete`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.Delete) standard function. You can specify any character by its numeric value with the `#` syntax, and the compiler can usually figure out whether it needs to represent an AnsiChar or a WideChar.

```
procedure RemoveNullCharacters(var s: WideString);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  i := 1;
  while i < Length(s) do
    if s[i] = #0 then
      Delete(s, i, 1)
    else
      Inc(i);
end;
```

But that may re-allocate the string many times (once for each null character). To avoid that, you can pack the string in-place:

```
procedure RemoveNullCharacters(var s: WideString);
var
  i, j: Integer;
begin
  j := 0;
  for i := 1 to Length(s) do
    if s[i] <> #0 then begin
      Inc(j);
      s[j] := s[i];
    end;
  if j < Length(s) then
    SetLength(s, j);
end;
```

Those functions will work for any of Delphi's string types; just change the parameter type.

Comment: The data comes in from a legacy system so I haven't got any way of sorting out the underlying issue...

Answer (score 6):

Those are not extra nulls. They're part of the string.

You should do some reading on multi-byte characters, which includes WideStrings. Characters are more than one byte in size, and some of those extra bytes are NULLs.

You might start here with Nick Hodges' [articles](http://dn.codegear.com/article/38437) on Unicode, written when Delphi 2009 was first released to help people transition from single-byte characters to multi-byte ones. There are three articles in the series, IIRC.