# How to read a text file that contains 'NULL CHARACTER' in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I have a text file that contains many NULL CHARACTERS and its encoding is UTF8.

I loaded the file using `RichEdit1.Lines.LoadFromFile(FileName,Encoding)` stoped after the first Null Character and it didn't load the rest of file.

Is there any help. How can I remove NULL Chars from a text file.

**BTW My text file encoding is UTF8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Reading* the file shouldn't be a problem. Rather, the problem is more likely when you try to store the data in a rich-edit control. Those controls don't accept arbitrary binary data. You need to ensure you only put *text* in that control.

Load the file into an ordinary string or stream:

```
var
  s: string;
  ss: TStringStream;

s := TFile.ReadAllText(FileName);
```

Then remove the invalid characters. `#0` is the notation in Delphi to represent a null character. Ordinarily, we might use `StringReplace` to remove characters:

```
s := StringReplace(s, #0, '', [rfReplaceAll]);
```

However, it's not binary-safe; it stops at null characters. Instead, you'll need a different function for removing those characters. [I've demonstrated that before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3685055/33732). Call that function to adjust the string:

```
RemoveNullCharacters(s);
```

Finally, put the data in the rich-edit control:

```
ss := TStringStream.Create(s);
try
  RichEdit1.Lines.LoadFromStream(ss, Encoding);
finally
  ss.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you worked perfect :)) My problem solved!

btw, I deleted the 'stringReplace' line because of this error: "Cannot assign to a read-only property"

Thanks again.

Comment: I'm confused that you think my previous code solved your problem. You point out that `DataString` cannot be assigned to. Changing the value of that property was *key* to answering the question you asked, which was how to remove null characters. Without that line, you're not removing anything. I've changed the code so that it removes the characters prior to loading the control.

Comment: Your last code didn't remove #0 but i could load the whole text (+ Null chars) into a richedit. Your new code works perfect too. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it is a UTF8 and not a UNICODE file? As you may know UNICODE is two bytes, where first one is a null character for non UNICODE languages, for example Chinese and the like.
Have you try to open the file with the IDE editor? Open it, select all the text (Ctrl+A) and copy (Ctrl+C) create a new empty text file and paste (Ctrl+V) the text. 
Save the new file and try the RichEdit with this new file.

Comment: No i know it's utf-8. I said many because it has 40-50 NULL Chars. But my text length is about 750 chars.

Comment: How do you know it is UTF-8? Did you create the file yourself? A UTF-8 encoded text file should not have any nulls in it. Unless the file is actually a binary file that has multiple UTF-8 encoded strings in it with nulls as delimiters between them, in which case you should be reading the file as a binary file and not as a text file.